# Build and package SharePoint2010 solution from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio

Are there any scripts to build and package a SharePoint2010 solution from directly from PowerShell, instead from Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 1):

There is a 3-part series on using PowerShell to deploy [SharePoint solutions here..](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/Deploying-your-solution-with-PowerShell-Part-1.aspx)